# Compile openjdk 7 on arm ubuntu

Tags: jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

I am trying to compile openjdk 7 on my arm ubuntu:

```
make all ALLOW_DOWNLOADS=true DISABLE_HOTSPOT_OS_VERSION_CHECK=ok
```

Then I received this error:

```
g++ -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIA32 -I/home/darklord/Develop/jdk7/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims -I/home/darklord/Develop/jdk7/hotspot/src/share/vm -I/home/darklord/Develop/jdk7/hotspot/src/cpu/x86/vm -I/home/darklord/Develop/jdk7/hotspot/src/os_cpu/linux_x86/vm -I/home/darklord/Develop/jdk7/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm -I/home/darklord/Develop/jdk7/hotspot/src/os/posix/vm -I/home/darklord/Develop/jdk7/hotspot/src/share/vm/adlc -I../generated -DASSERT -DTARGET_OS_FAMILY_linux -DTARGET_ARCH_x86 -DTARGET_ARCH_MODEL_x86_32 -DTARGET_OS_ARCH_linux_x86 -DTARGET_OS_ARCH_MODEL_linux_x86_32 -DTARGET_COMPILER_gcc -DCOMPILER2 -DCOMPILER1  -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -D_REENTRANT -fcheck-new -fvisibility=hidden -m32 -march=i586 -pipe -Werror -g -c -o ../generated/adfiles/adlparse.o /home/darklord/Develop/jdk7/hotspot/src/share/vm/adlc/adlparse.cpp 
g++: error: unrecognized argument in option '-march=i586'
```

It seems it is trying compile using x86 configuration. So how can I make the build pass on ARM machine?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify proper architecture option for g++. Reference [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/ARM-Options.html).

> -march=name
>       This specifies the name of the target ARM architecture. GCC uses this name to determine what kind of instructions it can emit when
>   generating assembly code. This option can be used in conjunction with
>   or instead of the -mcpu= option. Permissible names are: `armv2',`
>   armv2a', `armv3',`armv3m', `armv4',`armv4t', `armv5',`armv5t',
>   `armv5te',`armv6', `armv6j',`iwmmxt', `ep9312'.

Please make sure you refer proper version docs of [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)